# Why does windows not run hidden files in startup folder?

Tags: windows, boot

I was wondering about why my hidden file `startCalculator.exe` in my `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder doesn't run.

So can abybody tell me if there is any way to make windows run a hidden file at startup?

I am making the file hidden by this command in cmd: `attrib +s +h filename`.

The executable does run on startup when visible but not when hidden.

Why is this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Hiding a file does not hide its window when it executes.

Comment: @AFH he never said it would.. he is saying very clearly I think, that he is finding that when an executable file in the startup folder has the hidden attribute set, then it does not start up.. nothing about windows being hidden or not hidden, he says it doesn't start up. And when it doesn't have the hidden attribute set, it starts up. And he wants it to start up.  I haven't tested what he has said, but that's what he is saying.. Telling him that windows don't get hidden when the hidden attribute is set, is a red herring, he never suggested they do.

Comment: @AFH and when he said "windows" e.g. "Why does windows not run hidden files in startup folder?"  and "can abybody tell me if there is any way to make windows run a hidden file at startup? "   He was talking about the operating system, microsoft windows. Not about the windows that some programs have!

Comment: @barlop - I cannot understand why the questioner would wish to hide a file in the start-up folder: he has already found that hiding stops it running, so why do it? I was trying to guess that a reason might be confusion between the different senses of hidden. I'm not confused, but he may be.

Comment: @AFH maybe he's writing some spying software or maybe he's just curious or maybe he's a white hat type (wanting to know if a black hat type can do that), or maybe he has some bad motivations.. but ultimately it's still a reasonable technical question, whatever his reasons.

Comment: Hi! Barlop, you are right, it is simply for curiosity. I am not trying to create any sort of harmful programs but i would love to know why windows is not running the hidden file and how you could make it run a hidden file... I would never ever ever try to harm anybody and i hate people who is silly life enough to do so

Comment: It is not surprising that hiding a file will stop it executing, so I still don't understand why you want to do this. If you want to obscure files in the start-up folder, you could try hiding it or directories higher up the tree.

Comment: @AFH Gotcha, i did some research about what directories would be loaded upon startup and now i figured out how i should approach this. Thank you

Comment: @AFH   how can you possibly say that it's not surprising if hiding a file will stop it executing.. As if to suggest that a hidden file won't execute.. Why don't you try attrib +h blah.bat and then try running blah.bat and you'll see it runs.

Comment: @barlop - I am perfectly aware of that, and I certainly didn't say that hidden files could not be run. The execution of the start-up folder is more analogous to `for %f in (*) do start %f`: try this with a hidden file. I don't know how closely this reflects what happens, but I would not be at all surprised if it worked this way, which is what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does it for security reasons. If a virus program somehow manage to copy itself in the startup folder and set it's property to system file and hidden file. It would be very difficult to detect.

Not only the hidden files, if you place a program in startup folder, that requires admin privilages to execute, it will not run either.

Here is what you can do in both cases.

- Place your file somewhere else (or in the startup folder, it doesn't matter).
- Create a batch (.bat) file that executes your main file.
- place the bat file in the startup folder.

*Note: You will get a command prompt window during startup, but there are ways to fix that. What you can do is: generate an exe from that bat file (there are programs available to do that, just google) with hidden window.*

Comment: "Windows does it for security reasons" Do you have a reference for this?